# How to display a ListView and Other Controls in a ScrollView?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-binding

I want to display a `ListView` and other controls inside a `ScrollView`. All is bound to a `ViewModel`. My attempts failed because it's not recommend to put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollView`. As I use a complex `ViewCell` `DataTemplate`, I did not consider to add my items in the code behind file as `Buttons` instead of a `ListView`.

Hope someone can show me a Xaml or CS pattern to achieve my goal.

Please only suggest a solution which works on iOS and Android!

Thanks

Eric

Comment: Please, show the code you are having problems with.
Also, check my asnwer on this other question. It might be a duplicate of yours:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38228008/xamarin-forms-two-listviews-stacked/38232920#38232920

Comment: Thanks. This guy from your answered related question talks about to stacked ListViews. In have on top one ListView and below that ListView 10 Labels and one Button. All alignment is vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This is XAML code

```
<ScrollView Padding="2">
  <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout>
    <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
      <ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding UsersList}" SeparatorVisibility="None" x:Name="YourListView" RowHeight="50">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="5">
                    <Button Text="{Binding UserName}" WidthRequest="115" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#4b76c4" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Avenir Book"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
    </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
   </Grid>
  </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and .cs file you need set BindingContext

```
 BindingContext = new YourViewModel();
```

Comment: Thanks . I will try .

Comment: Tried that XAML but it doesn't work regarding my question.

Comment: Can you add any screenshot or sample code snippet that you are trying? that will help me to get clarity of your problem.

Comment: PLEASE read my answered solution. It works now  by usind the Evolve App code from 2016. Thank you.

Comment: Okay then fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

As [Rodrigo E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375718/rodrigo-e) suggested I [download](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve) the latest Xamarin Evolve App 2016. After digging through the code I adjusted/simplified the [FeedPage.xaml](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI/Pages/Home/FeedPage.xaml) in the solution to that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI;assembly=XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI"
xmlns:pull="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"
x:Class="XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI.FeedPage"
x:Name="FeedPage"
Title="Evolve Feed"
Icon="tab_feed.png"
BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundTable}">

<pull:PullToRefreshLayout
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}">
    <local:AlwaysScrollView
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                <local:NonScrollableListView
                    x:Name="ListViewSessions"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Sessions}">
                  <local:NonScrollableListView.RowHeight>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" Android="50" iOS="50" WinPhone="50"/>
                  </local:NonScrollableListView.RowHeight>
                    <local:NonScrollableListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Button Text="{Binding Title}" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="Green" />
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </local:NonScrollableListView.ItemTemplate>
                </local:NonScrollableListView>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Padding="0" Spacing="0" BackgroundColor="Green">
                <Button Text="OTHER" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" />
                <Button Text="OTHER" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" />
                <Button Text="OTHER" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" />
                <Button Text="OTHER" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" />
                <Button Text="OTHER" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" />
                <Button Text="OTHER" BackgroundColor="Blue" TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </local:AlwaysScrollView>
</pull:PullToRefreshLayout>
```

There are a few things to do:

1. In the [FeedViewModel.cs](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.Clients.Portable/ViewModel/FeedViewModel.cs) I added that code for a quick test:

   ```
      async Task ExecuteLoadSessionsCommandAsync()
   {
       if (LoadingSessions)
           return;

       LoadingSessions = true;

       try
       {
           NoSessions = false;
           Sessions.Clear();
           OnPropertyChanged("Sessions");
           #if DEBUG
           await Task.Delay(1000);
           #endif
           var sessions = await StoreManager.SessionStore.GetNextSessions();

           var testSessions = new List<Session>();
           testSessions.Add(new Session
           {
               Title = "TEST"
           });

           testSessions.Add(new Session
           {
               Title = "TEST"
           });

           testSessions.Add(new Session
           {
               Title = "TEST"
           });


           sessions = testSessions;
           if(sessions != null)
               Sessions.AddRange(sessions);

           NoSessions = Sessions.Count == 0;
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           ex.Data["method"] = "ExecuteLoadSessionsCommandAsync";
           Logger.Report(ex);
           NoSessions = true;
       }
       finally
       {
           LoadingSessions = false;
       }

   }
   ```
2. You have to reference the package Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh to get the Pull-to-Refresh behavor.
   This is in that namespace referenced: xmlns:pull="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"
3. You have to Copy the [AlwaysScrollView](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI/Controls/AlwaysScrollView.cs) , [NonScrollableListView](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI/Controls/NonScrollableListView.cs) to your PCL library.
   refercene it with: xmlns:local="clr-namespace:"
4. In your iOS Project add that custom ListView Renderer:

   public class NonScrollableListViewRenderer : ListViewRenderer
   {

   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);
       if (Control != null)
           Control.ScrollEnabled = false;

   }
   }

   public class AlwaysScrollViewRenderer : ScrollViewRenderer
   {
   public static void Initialize()
   {
       var test = DateTime.UtcNow;
   }
   protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);
       this.AlwaysBounceVertical = true;
   }
   }

See file: [Renderer](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.iOS/Renderers/NonScrollableListViewRenderer.cs)

5. Put that CollectionChanged Handler in your Code-behind file:

   ViewModel.Sessions.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => 
   {
   var adjust = Device.OS != TargetPlatform.Android ? 1 : -ViewModel.Sessions.Count + 1;
   ListViewSessions.HeightRequest = (ViewModel.Sessions.Count * ListViewSessions.RowHeight) - adjust;
   };

See File FeedPage.cs.xaml: [FeedPage.cs.xaml](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/blob/master/src/XamarinEvolve.Clients.UI/Pages/Home/FeedPage.xaml.cs)